# Filter by field only if it exists, elastic search

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I have a date field in my documents and I want to return only documents that have a date less than now - 5m, however not all my documents have the filed, they only recieve on the first time they get individually queried.

```
 documents = es.search(index='index_name', size=10000, body={
          "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
                {
              "range": {
                  "time_lockout": {
                      "lt": "now-5m"
                  }
              }
          }
      ],
      "filter": [

      ],
      "should": [

      ],

      "must_not": [
      ]
    }
  }})
```

So my pseudo code would be,

```
if `time_lockout` exists
    give documents that are now-5 including all documents thats dont have `time_lockout` 

Exclude documents that dat range falls withon that 5 minute window
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update the query to below:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "range": {
            "time_lockout": {
              "lt": "now-5m"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "must_not": [
              {
                "exists": {
                  "field": "time_lockout"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```